# Google Analytics - Redundant host name

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console

I am an absolute rookie at google analytics and would really appreciate some help.
I got a notification
`Redundant Hostnames
Property xxxxxxx.com.au is receiving data from redundant hostnames.`

So I apparently I must create a filter. The preffered domain is set as `wwww.mysite.com.au`

The filter I created looks like this

[image]

Is this correct does this resolve the`www.mysite.com.au` **(preffered)** to `http:mysite.com.au`?

Basically I would just like to know if the filter is correct and if we will get correct data for http:mysite.com.au and www.mysite.com.au??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redundant Hostnames means that there is more than one domain that can be used to access a particular page.

For example, the domain example.com has redundant hostnames because it is accessible from www.example.com and example.com or even by its ip address.

For optimal user experience and SEO practices, webmasters set 301 redirects to one consolidated domain, so if you want your site be http://example.com you make http://www.example.com and XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX IP of it 301 redirect to http://example.com

Comment: ok the .htaccess has been changed but the google filter, should I ignore the message set it up what should I do...in google analytics? Keeping in mind www is preffered as per 301 redirect

Comment: With time that alert in GA should disappear automatically. But if you've tested that all versions of your domain now open just one version and the alert in GA is annoying, you can set to ignore it, and choose a time of ignoring.